# Default size for Oracle output parameter

Tags: oracle, parameters, oracle11g, output, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem, I'm creating a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SIZE_OUT
( 
    MSGTEXT    OUT VARCHAR2
) IS 

BEGIN  

    --The next text has 200 characters
    MSGTEXT := '10101201212012012012012120121212134541010101011111111110000000010101000000000001111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000023401654421524546545gh4g4h4ghdgj5dghj4dgj4j4ghj4ghj1101123m';

END TEST_SIZE_OUT;
/
```

but when I assign to `MSGTEXT` a text with more of 201 characters and I execute this procedure, it generates this error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Sine `MSGTEXT` is an out parameter, the caller is responsible for its size. How is it called? Can you share the full scenario?

Comment: I call it from java code. This procedure isn't call from other procedure, or function, or anything else.

Comment: @Leonardo How do you register the output parameter when initializing the `callableStatement` in your Java code ?

Comment: That is a problem, I don't have access to java code, I have to resolve it in Oracle. In this moment I'm creating a subtype to test it.

Comment: No, I don't how to use the SUBTYPE globally. The only solution that I have is return the text in a cursor

Comment: Test it for being **1**. And also, call it from anonymous block and see what it returns

Comment: We are missing the java side.  Try running it in an anonymous block and declare the return as varchar2(300).  For IN parameters OCI looks to the caller to see how big the variable is.  For OUT parameters OCI relies on the caller to know what it is getting and then OCI transfers the information.  We can't really help you without the other side of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a query window or just with SQPLus:

```
declare

msg varchar(300) ;

begin

   test_size_out(msg);

end;
```

Unless I am mistaken this will work just fine with 250 chars in the string, but not 301.

You also might want to prefix your stored procedures with SP, functions with F packages with PKG etc.

Comment: Yes, in this block it works, because in this block the caller of the SP defines the size of the output parameter, but I need to know if there is a way to prove it without doing this. I think that is a problem of the client, I'm using sqqldeveloper for execute this procedure, but in other like pl-sql developer it works.

Comment: Ok, so in SQL Developer when you execute an SP it sets up a little runtime environment for you.  If you look ABOVE where you set the values you will see the declared varchar.

Comment: Yes, I found how changes the default size for sqldeveloper. But I don't if Oracle has default size or just sqldeveloper. I sent it for test and I'm waiting for the answer.

Comment: Only is SQL Developer.  The very nature of a varchar means that the caller must allocate enough memory to bring in the varchar.  Typically this is a pointer.  OCI must re-alloc or JDBC simply hands the process a resource, which is then re-alloed by the JVM.  There is no magic.  If the caller sees the parameter definition as varcch2(n) it allocates that much memory.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer. I really needed to know it.